# Finding maximum time required to be in the top $1\%$ given normal distribution

Tags: statistics

I used to be a stats major many years ago but have some seemingly basic questions that someone needed help on. I'll be changing the values just to keep it simple. The question reads something like:

The time for an employee at a company to produce a product is normally distributed, with a mean of $10.5$ minutes, and a variance of $3$ minutes.

There is a competition where an employee receives a prize if they produce a product in the top $10\%$ of times. What is the maximum time that an employee can take to receive this prize?

This was my attempt:
Let $X \sim N(10.5,3)$ be the time taken for an employee to make one copy of the product and let $Z = \frac{X - 10.5}{3} \sim N(0,1)$.
We are seeking the value of $T$ where $T$ is the maximum time taken. So we are finding $T$ such that this equation holds:
$$P(X \le T) = 0.1$$
That's as far as I can go. Sorry if this doesn't seem like much. I've forgotten all my stats knowledge. I know I'll probably need to look at the top 1% quantile of a standard normal distribution or something along those lines..

Comment: The z-score denominator is the standard deviation, which is the square root of the variance.

Comment: If the variance is $3$ then this would be measured in $\text{minutes}^2$ (square minutes?).

Comment: Your title says $1$ percent, your post says $10$ percent. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct except that $X \sim N(10.5,3)$ implies $Z = \frac{X - 10.5}{\sqrt3} \sim N(0,1)$.
Therefore,
$$P(X \le T) = 0.1\\P(\frac{X - 10.5}{\sqrt3}\le\frac{T-10.5}{\sqrt3})=0.1\\\frac{T-10.5}{\sqrt3}=\Phi^{-1}(0.1)\approx-1.28\\T\approx8.28$$

Comment: Can you give a reasoning for the = 0.1 part? I can't think of how to explain it. And why it's not <= 0.1 instead of = 0.1.

Comment: $\frac{X - 10.5}{\sqrt3}$ is a $N(0,1)$ random variable, LHS is the cdf of a standard normal variable $\Phi(\frac{T-10.5}{\sqrt3})$ . Since we are only calculating the maximum time, I used $=$. In fact, $$P(X \le T) = 0.1\Leftrightarrow T=8.28$$$$P(X \le T) \le 0.1\Leftrightarrow T\le8.28$$